# update store element adds row in grid without removing the old version

Tags: dojo, dgrid, dstore

I would like updates to the dstore appearing in the dgrid without having to call refresh.

do you know why the grid does not remove the old row?

my records has no id property but Ive setup the idProperty correctly.
My grid is expected to receive multiple updates and calling to refresh would probably have performance implications.

So if you can point a way to throttle refresh events it can also help.

Thanks,
  Nimrod.

Comment: it is customary to provide the minimal amount of code that reproduces the problem you are trying to solve,so you can show the code, what your output looks like and what you would like it to look like. StackOverflow's editor has a code block formatter so you can indicate what parts of your post are code.

Answer (score 0):

dgrid listens to change events if the store provides them. dstore's [`Trackable`](https://github.com/SitePen/dstore/blob/master/docs/Stores.md#trackable) mixin adds change events to the store. Try mixing in `Trackable` to your store and you should see dgrid automatically render in response to any of the store's add/put/remove calls.